# Keep XML entities in output (jSoup)

Tags: java, html, groovy, escaping, jsoup

I'm using jsoup to do some xml processing. Problem is, it is replacing xml entities, ie.: `&#187;` with html entities: `&raquo;`

How could I keep original (xml) entities?

Groovy script:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document
import org.jsoup.nodes.Entities
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser

String HTML_STRING = '''
    <html>
    <div></div>
    <div>Some text &#187;</div>
    </html>
  '''

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(HTML_STRING.getBytes("UTF-8")), "UTF-8", "", Parser.xmlParser())
doc.outputSettings().charset("UTF-8")
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.base)


println doc.toString()
```

Result:

```
<html> 
 <div></div> 
 <div>
  Some text &raquo;
 </div> 
</html>
```

If I use **`Entities.EscapeMode.xhtml`** the result is:

```
<html> 
 <div></div> 
 <div>
  Some text »
 </div> 
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just checked the API/source and some of the discussions. It appears this isn't possible natively. I guess your options are translating them back manually or extending [Entities class](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes/Entities.java) to suit your needs.

Comment: Yes, I had to modify following methods: Entities class: String escape(String string, CharsetEncoder encoder, EscapeMode escapeMode). Tokeniser class:  char[] consumeCharacterReference(Character additionalAllowedCharacter, boolean inAttribute)

Comment: You may wish to create an issue on the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues) for this.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use a combination of `EscapeMode.xhtml` (which is the default if you use the XML parser, not the HTML parser), and `ascii` as the output character set.

The default output charset is UTF-8, and jsoup will prefer to not use entity escapes if the output charset supports the character directly (because why waste CPU and bandwidth with unnecessary escapes).

If you change the output charset to `ascii` using [`Document.OutputSettings.charset("ascii")`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html#charset-java.lang.String-) you'll get the output you want.

You also probably want to set the output syntax to [XML](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.html#xml) if you are working with HTML, as otherwise the HTML parser will try to make the output confirm to HTML and can munge your XML DOM tree.

<sub>(Source: author of jsoup)</sub>