# On Jsoup identity transform

Tags: jsoup

I want to see if I can get back the original string with Jsoup after a transform.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html><body><span>&rarr;</span></body></html>");
String str = doc.toString();
System.out.println(str);
```

I'd like the output to be equivalent HTML (formatting aside).
Here the "rarr" string is mutilated.
So, what function do I have to use?

Comment: It's similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656463/keep-xml-entities-in-output-jsoup

Comment: I created an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/660).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pete Houston](https://github.com/petehouston) took me on the track in the [issue 660](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/660).

You can do it using:

```
doc
  .outputSettings()
  .charset("ascii")
  .escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.extended);
String str = doc.toString();
```

Output would be:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <span>&srarr;</span>
 </body>
</html>
```

**BUT** output is slightly different (`&srarr;` instead of `&rarr;`) from the input because:

> according to the HTML5 named character references,
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/named-character-references.html
>
> `&srarr;` is the same as `&rarr;` also, same as `&RightArrow;`,
>   `&ShortRightArrow;` ...
>
> as you know, jsoup do validation (escape/unescape) while processing
>   input and mapping the HTML entities defined in entities-*.properties;
>   well, since there are several entities' names represent in same
>   Unicode value `\u02192` in your case, the mapping is done with the first
>   match if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks ! This works and its valuable to have a simple function encapsulating this complex sequence of commands to generate reasonable HTML.  Why can't doc.html() do it ?